# How to say "shake hands" (or handshake) in Latin?

Tags: idiom

In [Galatians 2:9](https://biblehub.com/galatians/2-9.htm) there is a reference to a handshake between Paul and other Apostles:

> So, James, Cephas and John, these leaders, these pillars, shook hands with Barnabas and me as a sign of partnership: we were to go to the pagans and they to the circumcised.

On this respect, the Nova Vulgata reads:

> Iacóbus et Cephas et Ioánnes, qui videbántur colúmnæ esse, **déxteras dedérunt** mihi et Bárnabæ communiónis, ut nos in gentes, ipsi autem in circumcisiónem;

(texts are taken from [here](https://universalis.com/L/0/readings.htm))

So, they are not equivalent. The English one expresses the type of act, with the Latin expressing the way the act is performed. The latter is more akin to the Spanish case, where a handshake (*apretón de manos*) is also said *dar la mano* (*dare manum*). Is there a more general way to describe a handshake in Latin than that of the action performed?

Comment: Just for the sake of clarification: you are asking for an appropriate noun (or noun phrase) that roughly approximates the English noun "handshake"?

Comment: @EthanBierlein That's certainly the ideal case, but might not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cursory search of Smith & Hall provides no results for "handshake." A quick search for [*dextrās*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=dextras) or [*dextrās~iungere*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=dextras~iungere) on PHI's online word search tool, however, will provide a plethora of results. It generally seems that there are two accepted ways of expressing *to shake hands*: either *dext(e)rās jungere* or *dext(e)rās conjungere*. E.g:

> "Avidī conjungere dextrās ārdēbant"
>   "They burned, eager to join hands"
>
> *Vergil, Aeneid 1.514-515*

If you need to express the word "handshake" or discuss the act of shaking hands, an expression utilizing the gerund of *jungere* or *conjungere* would be acceptable; i.e: *dext(e)rās jungendum* or *dext(e)rās conjugendum*.

The phrasing provided in your original question, *dext(e)rās dare*, also works equally well. If you wish to express the word "handshake" or discuss the act of shaking hands with the verb *dō* instead, you'd again utilize the gerund: *dext(e)rās dandum*.